# Nifi JSON ETL: Custom Transformation Class not found with JoltTransformJSON Processor

Tags: java, etl, apache-nifi, jolt

I'd like to use my custom JSON transformation that implements the com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Transform interface.

I use "Custom Transformation Class Name" and "Custom Module Directory" like this:

[image]

However, I cannot get the JoltTransformJSON processor to use it; I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
2019-04-01 14:30:54,196 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.n.p.standard.JoltTransformJSON JoltTransformJSON[id=b407714f-0169-1000-d9b2-1709069238d7] Unable to transform StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=72dc471b-c587-4da9-b54c-eb46247b0cf4,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1554129053747-21203, container=default, section=723], offset=607170, length=5363],offset=0,name=72dc471b-c587-4da9-b54c-eb46247b0cf4,size=5363] due to java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sentilo.nifi.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sentilo.nifi.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sentilo.nifi.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.lambda$new$0(BoundedLocalCache.java:3373)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2037)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2020)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:112)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:67)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.getTransform(JoltTransformJSON.java:316)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.onTrigger(JoltTransformJSON.java:277)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sentilo.nifi.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.jolt.TransformFactory.getCustomTransform(TransformFactory.java:65)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.createTransform(JoltTransformJSON.java:346)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.lambda$setup$0(JoltTransformJSON.java:324)
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.lambda$new$0(BoundedLocalCache.java:3366)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I compiled the class together with all its dependencies with the maven-assembly-plugin and placed it in the directory "/data/bin/nifi-1.9.1/jolt_modules".
The directory and the jar are readable.

I also have tried to add the classname to the operation in spec as in [here](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/test/resources/json/chainr/transforms/loadsGoodTransform.json)), but Ii seems that it's the "Custom Module Directory" that does no effect for some reason...

*EDIT: I complete the answer with the code of ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB, in case somebody finds it useful. Is just converts Sentilo messages stored in Elasticsearch to OpenTSDB datapoints, flattening some nested JSON structures on the way.*

```java
package org.sentilo.nifi.elasticsearch;

import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.SpecDriven;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Transform;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.exception.TransformException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.sentilo.agent.historian.domain.OpenTSDBDataPoint;
import org.sentilo.agent.historian.utils.OpenTSDBValueConverter;
import org.sentilo.common.domain.EventMessage;
import org.sentilo.nifi.elasticsearch.model.Hits;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.sentilo.agent.historian.utils.OpenTSDBValueConverter.replaceIllegalCharacters;


public class ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB implements SpecDriven, Transform {

    private final Object spec;

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB() {
        this.spec = "{}";
    }

    @Inject
    public ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB( Object spec ) {
        this.spec = spec;
    }

    public Object transform( final Object input ) {

        try{
            Hits hits = mapper.readValue(input.toString(), Hits.class);
            List<EventMessage> newEventList = new ArrayList<EventMessage>();
            List<OpenTSDBDataPoint> dataPoints = new ArrayList<OpenTSDBDataPoint>();

            for(EventMessage event : hits.hits) {

                if (OpenTSDBValueConverter.isComplexValue(event.getMessage())) {
                    addComplexValueToQueue(event,newEventList);
                } else {
                    addSimpleValueToQueue(event, newEventList);
                }
            }

            for(EventMessage event2 : newEventList) {
                OpenTSDBDataPoint dp = unmarshal(event2);
                dataPoints.add(dp);
            }

            return dataPoints;

        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new TransformException(e.getMessage());
        }


    }


    private void addComplexValueToQueue(final EventMessage event, List<EventMessage> eventList) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        // Flatten JSON message into N measures
        final String metricName = OpenTSDBValueConverter.createMetricName(event);
        final Map<String, Object> unfoldValues = OpenTSDBValueConverter.extractMeasuresFromComplexType(metricName, event.getMessage());
        for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> e : unfoldValues.entrySet()) {
            final EventMessage newEvent = new EventMessage();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(newEvent, event);
            newEvent.setTopic(e.getKey());
            newEvent.setMessage(e.getValue().toString());
            eventList.add(newEvent);
        }
    }

    private void addSimpleValueToQueue(final EventMessage event, List<EventMessage> eventList) {
        // The value should be long, float or boolean
        try {
            final Object numericValue = OpenTSDBValueConverter.getSimpleValue(event.getMessage());
            final String metricName = OpenTSDBValueConverter.createMetricName(event);
            event.setMessage(numericValue.toString());
            event.setTopic(metricName);
            eventList.add(event);

        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            // Probably String or some non-numeric value that we cannot store in OpenTSDB. Pass
            return;
        }
    }

    public static OpenTSDBDataPoint unmarshal(final EventMessage event) throws ParseException {
        final OpenTSDBDataPoint dataPoint = new OpenTSDBDataPoint();

        dataPoint.setMetric(event.getTopic());
        dataPoint.setValue(OpenTSDBValueConverter.getSimpleValue(event.getMessage()));
        if (event.getPublishedAt() != null) {
            dataPoint.setTimestamp(event.getPublishedAt());
        } else {
            dataPoint.setTimestamp(event.getTime());
        }

        dataPoint.setTags(createTags(event));

        return dataPoint;

    }

    private static Map<String, String> createTags(final EventMessage event) {
        final Map<String, String> tags = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.type.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getType()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.sensor.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getSensor()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.provider.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getProvider()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.component.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getComponent()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.alertType.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getAlertType()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.sensorType.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getSensorType()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.publisher.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getPublisher()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.tenant.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getTenant()));
        putTag(tags, OpenTSDBDataPoint.Tags.publisherTenant.name(), replaceIllegalCharacters(event.getPublisherTenant()));

        return tags;
    }

    private static void putTag(final Map<String, String> tags, final String tagName, final String tagValue) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(tagValue)) {
            tags.put(tagName, tagValue);
        }
    }
}
```

## Update

As indicated in the comments, the issue is not resolved yet and has been filed as a bug report. The latest status can be seen here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6213

Comment: could you please give more info(may be snippet of constructor) about ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB and the contents and MANIFEST of jar this class is located in.

Comment: Did the transformation work outside Nifi? Were you able to get other (trivial) examples of jolt transformations working in Nifi?

Comment: Hi Dennis, yes, trivial examples are working in my Nifi, as do Junit tests of the ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB class, so I assume this responds your question about working "outside" Nifi. I can only use a custom class when I add it to the global Nifi classpath. I've tried it with some very simple class and it worked. But ElasticsearchToOpenTSDB has dependencies to another project OSS (sentilo.io) and these unfortunately break Nifi (I guess some spring jars), so I cannot use it even the "dirty" way.

Comment: @pushpavanthar I completed the answer and included the source. The jar is built with the maven-assembly-plugin that includes all dependencies to the converter (mostly Sentilo dependencies). The manifest contains:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: 25.171-b11 (Oracle Corporation)

Comment: @elkarel Great to see that you share your findings for future readers. Please post it as an actual answer so people can find it more easily (and afterwards remove the edit from your question).

Comment: HI @DennisJaheruddin, actually I still have to find the way on how to integrate the  custom transform class in my Nifi. I parked it for a while, since I was unable to get it woring (i tried with stable and snapshot). I created this issue on Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6213. Are you able to use a custom class? I think I will abandon Jolt and use another processor, which is a pity, because I feel I'm almost there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not resolved yet and has been filed as a bug report. The latest status can be seen here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6213

Comment: We recently received a patch for 1.16.0-SNAPSHOT that may address your Jira ticket. Here is the related Jira that the contributor provided with links to his fix. You might want to try out 1.16.0 when it is released in the nearish future to see if it resolves your issue. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-9286